# Ant - run step when a condition is met

Tags: ant

I have a strange problem with ant. I want to execute a step conditionally, so I created really simple example:

```
<project name="TestProj" default="def">
<property name="prop1" value="xxx"/>


<target name="init">
    <echo message="init step"/>
</target>

<target name="def" depends="init">
    <echo message="def step"/>

    <condition property="should.run">
        <equals arg1="${prop1}" arg2="xxx"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="outside check"/>
</target>


<target name="yes" if="${should.run}" depends="def">
    <echo message="yeah,should run"/>
</target>

<target name="no" unless="${should.run}" depends="def">
    <echo message="no,dont run"/>
</target>
```

The output is:

```
init:
     [echo] init step

def:
     [echo] def step
     [echo] outside check
```

So, my conditional steps were not run at all.

What is wrong with my example? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`if` and `unless` take the name of a property to check for existence, rather than the value. So you should use `if="should.run"`, `unless="should.run"`.

Comment: Not quite. The behavior of the `if` and `unless` attributes changes depending on whether you provide them with a property name or a property reference. If the property `should.run` is set to the value of `false`, having `if="${should.run}` will cause the target to be skipped. However, with `if="should.run"` the target will still run.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be with your target dependencies, not your conditions. Your `yes` and `no` targets depend on `def`, not the other way around. So calling `def` will only run `def` and `init` (because `def` depends on `init`). You will need to make a third target or extension point that calls both `yes` and `no` in order for this to work as you expect.

```
<extension-point name="all" depends="yes,no" />
```

Note that there is some truth in the other answer posted earlier by PavelS. If you want to use property references as opposed to property names in your target conditions, you will have to modify your condition task to explicitly set the conditional property to `false` in the case that the boolean evaluation is false (otherwise the `condition` task simply won't set the property at all.

```
<condition property="should.run" value="true" else="false>
    <equals arg1="${prop1}" arg2="xxx" />
</condition>
```